# images not loading in html using webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, webpack

I'm having any issue loading images from a different folder than where my index.html file is located. Below is the message I am getting from the console.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/company-logo.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

**Here is my file directory**

[image]

**webpack.config.js**

```
const currentTask = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event
const path = require('path')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const fse = require('fs-extra')

const postCSSPlugins = [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('autoprefixer')
]

class RunAfterComile {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.done.tap('Copy images', function() {
            fse.copySync('./public/images', './dist/public/images')
        })
    }
}

let cssConfig = {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: ['css-loader?url=false', {loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {plugins: postCSSPlugins}}]
}

let pages = fse.readdirSync('./views').filter(function(file) {
    return file.endsWith('.html')
}).map(function(page) {
    return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: page,
        template: `./views/${page}`
    })
})

let config = {
    entry: './public/scripts/App.js',
    plugins: pages,
    module: {
        rules: [
            cssConfig
        ]
    }
}

if (currentTask == 'dev') {
    cssConfig.use.unshift('style-loader')
    config.output = {
        filename: 'bundled.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    }
    config.devServer = {
        before: function(app, server) {
            server._watch('./views/**/*.html')
        },
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './views'),
        hot: true,
        port: 3000
    }
    config.mode = 'development'
}

if (currentTask == 'build') {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        }
    })
    cssConfig.use.unshift(MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader)
    postCSSPlugins.push(require('cssnano'))
    config.output = {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
    config.mode = 'production'
    config.optimization = {
        splitChunks: {chunks: 'all'}
    }
    config.plugins.push(
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(), 
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: 'styles.[chunkhash].css'}),
        new RunAfterComile()
        )
}

module.exports = config
```

The css works perfectly fine. I seem to only be having problems with images.

I tried the following file paths but they didn't work. I think I am missing something.

**index.html**

1. `<img src="./company-logo.jpg" alt="dfgadfg">`
2. `<img src="../public/images/company-logo.jpg" alt="dfgadfg">`
3. `<img src="./images/company-logo.jpg" alt="dfgadfg">`

any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Able to see the images under `dist/public/images` folder after bundling? If so the slight modification of option 2 should work `<img src="./public/images/company-logo.jpg" alt="dfgadfg">` (Since `dist` content will be served from server the path `./public/images/...` should work).

Comment: @PrathapReddy hi, yes my images do appear in dist/public/images after bundling. However I need to be able to see the images during development phase, which isn't working at the moment.

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/public/images/company-logo.jpg` is this working? Or able to find out any clue with the help of network tab?

Comment: following message from the console. `Cannot GET /public/images/company-logo.jpg`. I should mention when I drag the `index.html` file from `dist` folder the images load just fine.

Comment: If you open `Source` tab in **Developer Tools**, you can find out if the images or loading or not.

Comment: ohh. Didn't know that. thank you. They are not loading in. only `index.html` and my `bundled.js` are.

Comment: Then you need `file-loader` for sure. It's similar to Loppik answer but you need to add the `outputPath` option

Comment: Check if they are loading in any folder path of `Souce` after adding `file-loader` with the `outputPath` mentioned in the answer

Comment: Updated my answer. Post the updates if there are any other issues. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
module: {
      rules: [
       {
         test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
         use: [
           'file-loader',
         ],
       },
      ],
    },
```

Comment: I added the following suggestion to my `config` variable in my `webpack.config.js` file. I installed the package using npm. Should I require in the package? Also what should the file path look like? Because it isn't working yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might require [file-loder](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader) to get the images correctly served

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      outputPath: 'images' // Chage this like 'public/images' or any other relative path to the root
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Try to inspect and check how the images are loading in `Source` tab of **Developer Tools**, change the `outputPath` accordingly.

#### Update

If images are still not loading to `Source` tab of browser, try importing it in your `App.js` (Entry point file)

```
....
import "../public/images/company-logo.jpg";

...
```

Comment: I was unable to load in the images using `file-loader`. After adding the import `"../public..." ` suggestion I was able to locate it in my  `bundled.js` file which means it was imported successfully(I think). How would I reference it in the HTML then?

Comment: No. The combination of both the steps (import and `file-loader` rule) will bring the images to the `Source` tab. See if there is any `images` or `public/images` folder contains the image file in browser Developer Tools.